# Best way to check for inner exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception

I know sometimes innerException is null

So the following might fail:

```
 repEvent.InnerException = ex.InnerException.Message;
```

Is there a quick ternary way to check if innerException is null or not?

Comment: You might wish to revisit your accepted answer.  jrista's answer is better than the others, because an InnerException can have its own InnerException.

Comment: Keep in mind that ToString walks through the inner exceptions and combines them for you.  This can be a handy short-cut when logging.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
String innerMessage = (ex.InnerException != null) 
                      ? ex.InnerException.Message
                      : "";
```

Comment: Also, is it just me, or would it look a bit cleaner if the arguments were flipped and the `!=` changed to `==`.

Comment: @Noldorin - Sorry dude, I answered this and didn't check to see if I was first!  @JL - Noldorin was the first out of the chute with the correct answer, please transfer the accepted answer to him.

Comment: @Andrew: Heh, no need to apologise. :) I'm not one to be upset over the issue of a trivial matter, I was just curious as to JL's reason mainly.

Comment: Works but not for multiple nested exceptions

Answer (score 87):

Great answers so far. On a similar, but different note, sometimes there is more than one level of nested exceptions. If you want to get the root exception that was originally thrown, no matter how deep, you might try this:

```
public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    public static Exception GetOriginalException(this Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.InnerException == null) return ex;

        return ex.InnerException.GetOriginalException();
    }
}
```

And in use:

```
repEvent.InnerException = ex.GetOriginalException();
```

Comment: Am I missing something here or is ex.GetOriginalException() for innerException not top level ex?

Comment: I'm not sure what your asking. GetOriginalException will return the original exception that initiated the whole exception chain, regardless of whether there is only one exception (no InnerException at all), or many levels of InnerExceptions.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me find the InnerException of an exception thrown by EntityFramework.

Comment: I am not sure which version of .Net Framework provides GetOriginalException, but all I can see is GetBaseException(). Is that the same?

Comment: He's saying you should implement your own method called GetOriginalException.  But yes, it would seem GetBaseException() does the same thing.

Comment: I just had an example where I tried to use GetBaseException for a Task<String> for HttpClient, and it continued to just return a higher-level exception. When I implemented this solution, it returned the "Machine actively refused.." message that I was looking for. Great work Jrista!

Comment: @DanChase This is because AggregationException is overriding GetBaseException. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.aggregateexception.getbaseexception?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_AggregateException_GetBaseException) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16565834/3479456)

Answer (score 50):

That's funny, I can't find anything wrong with [Exception.GetBaseException()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.getbaseexception.aspx)?

```
repEvent.InnerException = ex.GetBaseException().Message;
```

Comment: Great!, with this you don't have to do a custom method to navigate through all nested exceptions.

Comment: I just had an example where I tried to use GetBaseException for a Task<String> for HttpClient, and it continued to just return a higher-level exception. When I implemented Jrista's solution, it returned the "Machine actively refused.." message that I was looking for.

Comment: why isn't this answer yet accepted as the correct answer?

Comment: @Thameem There seems to be cases where this doesn't work (e.g. what Dan Chase said above). I'm having a similar problem

Answer (score 17):

The simplest solution is to use a basic conditional expression:

```
repEvent.InnerException = ex.InnerException == null ? 
    null : ex.InnerException.Message;
```

Comment: No problem at all, just that Andrew's code returned a string.

Comment: @JL: Actually, mind returns a `string` too. I just assumed from the code that you were calling the `string` property `InnerException` (just be confusing?). Never mind though.
@Andrew: Thanks. And though I don't at all mind, +1 to yours for the courtesy.

Comment: @Nordorin, Ah I see where the issue comes in, I've gone string because exceptions don't serialize well (if they do at all).

Comment: @JL: Exceptions that come with the .NET framework serialize fine, as all of them have a deserialization constructor. Custom exceptions may not serialize properly, but it is easy enough to add a deserialization constructor and override GetObjectData. Third-party extensions could be made serializable with a serialization surrogate.

Answer (score 15):

Why so much recursion in these answers?

```
public static class ExceptionExtensions
{
    public static Exception GetOriginalException(this Exception ex)
    {
        while(ex.InnerException != null)ex = ex.InnerException;
        return ex;
    }
}
```

Seems like a much more straight forward way to implement this.

Answer (score 12):

Its an old question but for future readers:

In addition to the answers already posted I think the correct way to do this (when you can have more than one InnerException) is [Exception.GetBaseException Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.getbaseexception%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

If you want the exception instance you should do this:

```
repEvent.InnerException = ex.GetBaseException();
```

If you are only looking for the message this way:

```
repEvent.InnerException = ex.GetBaseException().Message;
```

Answer (score 9):

With C# 6.0 you can use:

`string message = exception.InnerException?.Message ?? ""`;

This line of code is similar to:

`string message = exception.InnerException == null ? "" : exception.InnerException.Message`.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jerrynixon/archive/2014/02/26/at-last-c-is-getting-sometimes-called-the-safe-navigation-operator.aspx

Comment: ＋１  null-conditional and null-coalescing operators. The usage of `(ex.InnerException?.Message??"")` is convenient, readable and secure.

Answer (score 6):

With this code, you could be sure that you haven't lost any inner exception messages

```
catch (Exception exception)
{
   Logger.Error(exception.Message);
   while (exception.InnerException != null)
   {
       exception = exception.InnerException;
       Logger.Error(exception);
   }
}
```

Comment: I use the `while (ex.InnerException != null)` method often and find it very helpful. It can become incredibly verbose at times, however.

Answer (score 6):

With C# 6.0 you can do it in one line.

```
repEvent.InnerException = ex.InnerException?.Message;
```

for other feature of C# 6.0 click [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802602.aspx)

Comment: The best part with above code is, you no need to worry about null pointer exception i.e checking null before using it(explicitly).

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes also InnerException has an InnerException, so you can use a recursive function for it:

```
public string GetInnerException(Exception ex)
{
     if (ex.InnerException != null)
     {
        return string.Format("{0} > {1} ", ex.InnerException.Message, GetInnerException(ex.InnerException));
     }
   return string.Empty;
}
```

Comment: I'm all for digging down to the oldest exception, but there's really no reason to recurse here.  Just loop while inner exception is not null.

Comment: Is recursion evil or something?

Comment: E.g. in Entity Framework are usefully exceptions deep inside.

Comment: Recursion isn't evil, but it can be expensive, so if you don't need it, don't use it.  In the case of inner exceptions, you have no need to keep pushing the current state onto a stack so that you can continue where you left off, so why use recursion and pay this price?  There are also cases where recursion is much, much slower than regular iteration, such as calculating the Fib series.

Comment: Sweet! I added this as an extension method to be available project-wide

Comment: @StevenSudit, recursion cannot possibly be expensive here. There is no way in the world that he could blow the stack. The difference between the recursive and and iterative versions would be undetectable. The only thing worth worrying about would be which one is easier to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Yes:

```
if (ex.InnerException == null) {
    // then it's null
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another possible implementation that appends the messages and stack traces so we get them full:

```
private static Tuple<string, string> GetFullExceptionMessageAndStackTrace(Exception exception)
{
    if (exception.InnerException == null)
    {
        if (exception.GetType() != typeof(ArgumentException))
        {
            return new Tuple<string, string>(exception.Message, exception.StackTrace);
        }
        string argumentName = ((ArgumentException)exception).ParamName;
        return new Tuple<string, string>(String.Format("{0} With null argument named '{1}'.", exception.Message, argumentName ), exception.StackTrace);
    }
    Tuple<string, string> innerExceptionInfo = GetFullExceptionMessageAndStackTrace(exception.InnerException);
    return new Tuple<string, string>(
    String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", innerExceptionInfo.Item1, Environment.NewLine, exception.Message),
    String.Format("{0}{1}{2}", innerExceptionInfo.Item2, Environment.NewLine, exception.StackTrace));
}


[Fact]
public void RecursiveExtractingOfExceptionInformationOk()
{
    // Arrange
    Exception executionException = null;
    var iExLevelTwo = new NullReferenceException("The test parameter is null");
    var iExLevelOne = new ArgumentException("Some test meesage", "myStringParamName", iExLevelTwo);
    var ex = new Exception("Some higher level message",iExLevelOne);

    // Act 
    var exMsgAndStackTrace = new Tuple<string, string>("none","none");
    try
    {
        exMsgAndStackTrace = GetFullExceptionMessageAndStackTrace(ex);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        executionException = exception;
    }

    // Assert
    Assert.Null(executionException);

    Assert.True(exMsgAndStackTrace.Item1.Contains("The test parameter is null"));
    Assert.True(exMsgAndStackTrace.Item1.Contains("Some test meesage"));
    Assert.True(exMsgAndStackTrace.Item1.Contains("Some higher level message"));
    Assert.True(exMsgAndStackTrace.Item1.Contains("myStringParamName"));

    Assert.True(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(exMsgAndStackTrace.Item2));

    Console.WriteLine(exMsgAndStackTrace.Item1);
    Console.WriteLine(exMsgAndStackTrace.Item2);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class MyException : Exception
{
    private const string AMP = "\r\nInnerException: ";
    public override string Message
    {
        get
        {
            return this.InnerException != null ? base.Message + AMP + this.InnerException.Message : base.Message;
        }
    }

    public override string StackTrace
    {
        get
        {
            return this.InnerException != null ? base.StackTrace + AMP + this.InnerException.StackTrace : base.StackTrace;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may simply write like this:

```
repEvent.InnerException = ex.InnerException?.Message ?? string.Empty;
```

For get other type of error you may write like this:

```
string exception = $"\n{nameof(AccountViewModel)}.{nameof(AccountCommand)}. \nMessage: {ex.Message}. \nInnerException:{ex.InnerException}. \nStackTrace: {ex.StackTrace}";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use an exception filter to get more precise aiming.

`catch (Exception ex) when (ex.InnerException != null) {...}`

Please find more details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch#remarks)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way old and maybe this has already been answered in a comment I didn't see, but I needed this for a retry policy recently, to catch any inner exception of a given type

```cs
public static class ExceptionExtensions
    {
        public static bool ThisOrInnerIs<T>(this Exception exception, out T casted) where T : Exception
        {
            casted = exception as T;
            if (exception is T) return true;
                        
            if (exception.InnerException != null)
            {
                return ThisOrInnerIs(exception.InnerException, out casted);
            }

            return false;
        }
    }
```