# Sending Email using SMTP in C#

Tags: c#, smtp

**It just says "    Failure sending mail."
Not sure its the problem with the code or SMTP server ? Please help here is my code, the variables are send through a form and i have confirmed that all variables are ok

SMTP Settings is in Web.config**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="newsletter@abc.com">
        <network host="mail.abc.com" port="25" userName="newsletter@abc.com" password="abc#!@"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
    <system.web>

    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

**Code in C#**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Net.Mail;

public partial class SendMail : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
    protected void cmdSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MailMessage mMailMessage = new MailMessage();

        // address of sender
        mMailMessage.From = new MailAddress(txtFrom.Text);
        // recipient address
        mMailMessage.To.Add(new MailAddress(txtTo.Text));
        // Check if the bcc value is empty
        if (txtBcc.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            // Set the Bcc address of the mail message
            mMailMessage.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(txtBcc.Text));
        }

        // Check if the cc value is empty
        if (txtCc.Text != string.Empty)
        {
            // Set the CC address of the mail message
            mMailMessage.CC.Add(new MailAddress(txtCc.Text));
        }     // Set the subject of the mail message
        mMailMessage.Subject = txtSubject.Text;
        // Set the body of the mail message
        mMailMessage.Body = txtBody.Text;
        // Set the format of the mail message body as HTML
        mMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
        // Set the priority of the mail message to normal
        mMailMessage.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;

        // Instantiate a new instance of SmtpClient
        SmtpClient mSmtpClient = new SmtpClient();


        // Send the mail message
        try
        {
            mSmtpClient.Send(mMailMessage);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ;//log error
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            mMailMessage.Dispose();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where is your SMTP settings?

Comment: @Grant, as long as the settings exist in the app or web config they will be picked up.

Comment: @ I have addded the web.config

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I get "Failure sending mail." message

Comment: Have a look into the Event Viewer and see if you're getting any System or Application errors related to it.

Comment: try EnableSSL . and set port no 465

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a telnet command to check if you can send a mail.

Start-> type "telnet":

```
open smtp.server.com 25
Helo smtp.server.com 
Mail from:yourAdress@server.com
Rcpt to:yourAdress@server.com

Data
Subject:The life
OMG
.
Quit
```

If telnet isn't there, add it through add/remove windows features. See :[http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771275%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried Telnet it says C:\Windows\system32>telnet mail.abc.com 25
'telnet' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: Sorry... it is not commnand prompt.  Start-> type telnet

Comment: Installing Telnet, shall i check Telnet command on the Server or from any client machine ?

Comment: The problem was in SMTP Server its Fixed now thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

<strike>First, we didn't the specify the SMTP server name:</strike>

```
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient(@"abc.company.com");
```

Second, after specifying the SMTP server name like the snippet above, Make sure the firewall or Symantec (or some program like that) is not blocking the outbound request.

Comment: First, the settings are defined in the web config - so they don't need to be passed into the `ctor`.

Comment: As the OP pointed out, his SMTP information is in the config.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w355a94k.aspx

Comment: Wasn't there when I read the question.  Still, firewall or Symantec or something like that need to be verified.

Answer (score -1):

In your try catch block, you will need to go through all the exceptions.  Keep looping until `exception.innerexception` is null.  A more detailed error message will be found in the inner exception to why the mail message failed to be sent.  The outer exception and corresponding message will be generic and not that useful.

Some samples can be found here:

[Best way to check for inner exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456563/best-way-to-check-for-inner-exception#)

Here some Psuedo Code

```
   while (ex != null)
    {
        //LogThisException(ex);
        ex = ex.InnerException;
    }
```

Comment: Hmmm, usually there a better message in the inner exception.  Put a breakpoint right on this line:  lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;  and keep expanding out the ex.InnerException.