# Entity Framework generating Entity Data Model fails with error

Tags: entity-framework

I added just two tables into my database, using as always `update-database` command. Everything went nice, without any errors.

But now, when I try to generate Entity Data Model (`Entity Framework > View Entity Data Model`), I get an window with an error:

> Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Why? How to repair it? Reinstall Entity Framework Power Tools is not helpful at all.

Regards

EDIT:

Context:

```
    public DbSet<Order> Order { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Product> Product { get; set; }
```

Model:

```
[Table("Product")]
public class Product
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductId { get; set; }

    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime AddDate { get; set; }
    public bool del { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Order> OrderList { get; set; }
}

[Table("Order")]
public class Order
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OrderId { get; set; }

    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public string desc { get; set; }

    public virtual Product product { get; set; }
}
```

Without this code below, everything works nice - what is wrong?

Comment: Have you tried examining the inner exception in the debugger when the exception is thrown? That will usually give you some clue as to what's going wrong.

Comment: No I haven't - how to do it?

Comment: You can examine the exception in the debugger using watches, or by mousing over the objects (in visual studio), or you can do something like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456563/best-way-to-check-for-inner-exception, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hdwz4c0s%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Comment: yes, but I use this tool, like here - http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/jj593170.ViewEDMwithDesigner%28en-us,MSDN.10%29.png -> so how I can take any errors in debugger?

Comment: No problems here with the same code. EF Power Tools Beta 3 via Nuget.

Comment: and you have proper connection between Order and Product? I have still the same error

Comment: Yes, it's OK. What do you mean by _Without this code below_?