# Web Server returning http response as "An error occurred while executing the command definition."

Tags: angularjs, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6

I have my web application executing fine on localhost, however after deploying it to a remote web server (VM) I get.

> "An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the
>   inner exception for details."
>
> HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error)

I'm using AngularJS, WebApi, EF 6 Database First and IIS 7

How to troubleshoot and get inner exception details?

I verified the query with Sql Profiler (no issues).
I verified the Event logs (no issues)

Comment: hope this help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456563/best-way-to-check-for-inner-exception)

Comment: I'm looking for some hints or where to capture the global exceptions and what settings if so are required in Web.config, I tried CustomError Off mode, I believe that shows the yellow screen will a complete dump of inner exception, but that did not work, I tried remoteOnly as well. I can see the 500 exception only through browser debug tool (F12). I appreciate you pitching in though.

Comment: looks like a EF error. do you use any logger? like `NLog` or `log4Net`