# I'm trying to read from a custom file type in C#

Tags: c#

I'm trying to read and write from a custom file type that I created, like this:

```
public static byte[] writeTo(Structures.SearchDS s)
{
    var o = new MemoryStream();
    var b = new BinaryWriter(o);

    b.Write(s.magic);
    b.Write(s.name);
    b.Write(s.age);
    b.Write(s.b.ElementAt(0).Houseno);
    b.Write(s.b.ElementAt(0).location);

    return o.ToArray();
}

public static Structures.SearchDS readSearchFile(byte[] a)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(a);
    BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(ms);
    Structures.SearchDS ss = new Structures.SearchDS();
    ss.magic=br.ReadChars(5);
    ss.name = br.ReadString();
    ss.age = br.ReadUInt16();
    ss.b[0] = new Structures.House();
    ss.b[0].Houseno = br.ReadString();
    ss.b[0].location = br.ReadString();

    return ss;
}
```

Main method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

    // TODO: Implement Functionality Here

    byte[] testFile=Tools.writeTo(Tools.adding());
    File.WriteAllBytes("test3.search", testFile);

    Structures.SearchDS ss1 = Tools.Write(File.ReadAllBytes("test.search"));
    Console.WriteLine(ss1.age);
    Console.WriteLine(ss1.name);
    Console.WriteLine(ss1.magic);

    ss1.b[0] = new Structures.House();

    Console.WriteLine(ss1.b.ElementAt(0).Houseno);
    Console.WriteLine(ss1.b.ElementAt(0).location);
    Console.Write("Press any key to continue . . . ");
    Console.ReadKey(true);
}
```

but I keep getting the exception:

> End of stream exception

at

```
ss.name = br.ReadString();
```

I opened the file with a hex editor and I see my data written properly and file stream gives the following exceptions at the same time

> 'ms.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>
> 'ms.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

My data structures are:

```
public class SearchDS
{
    public char[] magic = { 'S', 'E', 'A', 'R', 'C', 'H' };
    public string name;
    public UInt16 age;
    public House[] b = new House[1];
}

public class House { public string Houseno; public string location; }
```

Comment: Use the debugger to see what the error is.

Comment: Use Visual Studio to dig into the exception.  Usually you'll find something like an inner exception that will give you a more specific error.

Comment: I did every object is initialized perfect except the ones on the read side. all data is written perfect but it doesn't read anything past the characters this is the exception I can't  shake what does it even mean 'ms.WriteTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
'ms.ReadTimeout' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' I dug dipper and the message says "timeouts are not supported in this stream"

Comment: @RobertHarvey is referring to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456563/best-way-to-check-for-inner-exception)

Comment: Are you simply reaching the end of the stream?

Comment: I checked and all inner exceptions are null

Comment: yes end of stream but it's not end of file I see the file on hex editor everything is written to the file

Comment: and it's not an error it's an exception

Comment: Show the code for Structures.SearchDS. You need to ensure your BinaryReader.Reads match your BinaryWriter.Writes for data type/size.

Comment: one more thing if it helps File.ReadAllBytes  returns the same array of bits as one in her  editor same order and everything

Comment: Why did you choose to create a custom file type? Is there some reason JSON or XML don't work for you?

Comment: Your main method does not call `readSearchFile`, it calls `Write`.

Comment: ya I fixed the call on main  it still the same.

Comment: I used a custom file because I'm doin a data structure assignment and in not allowed to use database for indexing for string search I use an n-tree and want to write the tree to file because it's too large

Comment: public class SearchDS
        {
            public char[] magic = { 'S', 'E', 'A', 'R', 'C', 'H' };
            public string name;
            public UInt16 age;
            public House[] b = new House[1];

        }
        public class House
        {
            public string Houseno;
            public string location;
        }

Comment: Specify the length of the strings you are read and writing.  You read method cannot tell when the strings end.. If you do not want to include a length then terminate with '\0'.

Comment: how do I include length the readstring method doesn't accept any parametters

Comment: You don't include length. The `WriteString` method writes the length, then the string; `ReadString` reads the length then the string. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You initialized `magic` with the six characters of "SEARCH", but you call `ReadChars` with **5**. This causes the very next read string to be incorrect; the `ReadString` tries to get the length to read, which is going to be initialized with the char **H** (well part of it... strings are Unicode). That length exceeds the remaining length you have available to you.