# When to examine for InnerException

Tags: c#, .net, exception, clr

When to examine the `InnerException` property of the `Exception` class and its derivatives? Microsoft's "Best practices for exceptions" doesn't provide any advise on when to examine for inner exceptions. Should I do it only when exceptions are rethrown and caught in my code? Should I do it always, even when I enclose in `try-catch` block standard functions like `System.IO.File.Move`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1456563/best-way-to-check-for-inner-exception/

Comment: What means "when to examine inner exceptions"? Are you asking when you should look at that property? If you are interested and it is `!= null`

Comment: The exception will often tell you to look at the inner exception, meaning *"I'm a bit vague so check the inner exception for some details"*

Comment: Sometimes I don't know how many times the exception has been rethrown, so I'm not supposed to believe, that inner exception doesn't contain other inner exception... So examine each exception for inner exceptions recursively? But nobody does that! And I think that Microsoft and other big company devs were smart enough to understand it and so: methods or classes that they provide hardly ever contain inner exceptions. But that's just my assumption. Somebody can confirm that assumption? So when to check for inner exceptions? Please, don't tell me "always"

Comment: @АлексейГоршков again: it comes down to simply: *is it useful for you* to check for inner exceptions? if so: do it; if not: don't. Usually, touching the inner exception should be routine in your top-level error logging code, and virtually completely absent elsewhere, but that's moot because checking *anything* on the exception is pretty rare elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

### Who might use such a feature?

Sometimes, developers convert one exception (typically one definied by Microsoft) into another exception (typically an exception defined on their own).

This can make an API simpler, e.g. as in the example you have given with `File.Move()`. Instead of the 7 possible Microsoft exceptions, such an API could just throw a simple "That didn't work" exception with details inside, so your code only needs to handle one type of exception.

### When to use it?

I would look into them during the development phase when using the 3rd party framework. If they tend to be empty, there's no value in writing code for it.

If you write a logger / tracer or generic debug output, I would definitely consider it.

Exceptions I know that have InnerExceptions:

- TargetInvocationException
- AggregateException

Comment: Thank you! That's a very good practical advise, I'll use this approach with 3rd parties!

Answer (score 2):

Ultmately the answer here is simply: whenever it is useful **for you** to do so, which is entirely contextual. For the *vast majority* of cases, it isn't actually worth checking much on the exception *at all* - other than reporting it; just "do the thing, oops, failed" - you should usually have more `using` and `finally` than `catch`, IMO - because **usually** there isn't anything useful you can do with an exception except bubble it upwards.

However, in some cases, there is useful context. Classic examples would be `AggregateException`, `TargetInvocationException` and `TypeInitializationException` or *anything* coming from `XmlSerializer`. Those are pretty rare, so you wouldn't want to start checking for them explicitly *unless* you have very good reason to expect them. In terms of your general error reporting code: yes it makes sense to log the inner exceptions, but `.ToString()` usually does that automatically, IIRC.

As an example from some real code involving `InnerException` - there is a scenario in my network code where I don't care about a *very specific* situation only detectable via the combination of outer and inner exception; `when` does this job for me:

```
try
{
    await _server.RunClientAsync(connection.Transport).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
catch (IOException io) when (io.InnerException is UvException uv && uv.StatusCode == -4077)
{ } //swallow libuv disconnect
```

(everything other than that scenario is bubbled)

Comment: So, can think of it such way: Is it really required to collect the INFO inside the exception or not is defined first by the context?

Comment: @АлексейГоршков I can't quite parse that - could you retry rephrasing? but: "is it useful to check?" is the ultimate question

Comment: "Whether to try to retrieve inner exception is defined by the information we want to get from the exception trace" - that's it, maybe oversimplified